# loss value deep learning model is inf

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I train a RNN deep learning model as bellow:

```
model = Sequential()
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=.5, stddev=1)
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2,input_shape=trainX.shape[1:] ,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='random_normal',bias_initializer=initializer))

model.add(LSTM(128 ,return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='random_normal',bias_initializer=initializer))

model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='random_normal', activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001),
              loss='mean_absolute_error',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

history = model.fit(trainX, y, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=500, batch_size=30)
```

the output of my model is:
[the loss validation value is decreased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eFLN.jpg)

I do normalization on my input data and there is no 'nan' or 'zero' in input data. My label is the Jaccard similarity on the word2vec input data and it is so simple label!!!
but I don't know, how can fix it?

Comment: Get rid of *all* your initializers (both for weights & biases); sticking to the default values is the most reasonable thing to do, especially as a beginner, except if you *have* to use a specific initializing and you *know exactly* what you are doing!

Comment: thanks for your response, I do that but there is no change in the output

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. the problem was the negative logarithm in preprocessing step